# Getting errors parsing text using Spacy using PySpark and Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I am trying to parse some text using spacy to get word dependencies. I am running PySpark in Anaconda with Jupyter notebooks.

Python version: 3.7.5

PySpark version: 2.4.4

Spacy version: 2.2.5

Anaconda version: 4.7.12

Jupyter version: 6.0.2

Here's a MVCE for the error:

```py
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def get_token_dep(text):
    if text:
        nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
        return [(token.text, token.tag_, token.head.text, token.dep_) for token in nlp(text)]
    else:
        return [['N/A']]
get_token_dep_udf = udf(get_token_dep, ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType())))

text_list = ['Chocolate is a food made from cacao beans.', 'Dessert is a course that concludes a meal.']
text_df = spark.createDataFrame(text_list, StringType())

text_df = text_df.withColumnRenamed(
    'value', 'text'
).withColumn(
    'parsed_text', get_token_dep_udf('text')
)

display(text_df.toPandas())
```

However, I am getting errors as follows:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-bc4e37a4051a> in <module>
----> 1 display(text_df.toPandas())

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   2141 
   2142         # Below is toPandas without Arrow optimization.
-> 2143         pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
   2144 
   2145         dtype = {}

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py in collect(self)
    532         """
    533         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 534             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    535         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    536 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o147.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 47, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\catalogue.py", line 8, in <module>
    import importlib.metadata as importlib_metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 366, in main
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 69, in read_command
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 580, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from spacy.util import load_model_from_init_py, get_model_meta
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
  File "strings.pxd", line 23, in init spacy.syntax.nn_parser
  File "strings.pyx", line 17, in init spacy.strings
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 16, in <module>
    import catalogue
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\catalogue.py", line 10, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 547, in <module>
    __version__ = version(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 509, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 482, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 183, in from_name
    dist = next(dists, None)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 425, in <genexpr>
    for path in map(cls._switch_path, paths)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 449, in _search_path
    if not root.is_dir():
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1358, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\py37\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyspark\\jars\\spark-core_2.11-2.4.4.jar'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3260)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\catalogue.py", line 8, in <module>
    import importlib.metadata as importlib_metadata
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 366, in main
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 241, in read_udfs
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 168, in read_single_udf
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 69, in read_command
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 580, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from spacy.util import load_model_from_init_py, get_model_meta
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import pipeline
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
  File "strings.pxd", line 23, in init spacy.syntax.nn_parser
  File "strings.pyx", line 17, in init spacy.strings
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 16, in <module>
    import catalogue
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\catalogue.py", line 10, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 547, in <module>
    __version__ = version(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 509, in version
    return distribution(distribution_name).version
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 482, in distribution
    return Distribution.from_name(distribution_name)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 183, in from_name
    dist = next(dists, None)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 425, in <genexpr>
    for path in map(cls._switch_path, paths)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py", line 449, in _search_path
    if not root.is_dir():
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1358, in is_dir
    return S_ISDIR(self.stat().st_mode)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\py37\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyspark\\jars\\spark-core_2.11-2.4.4.jar'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I have tried upgrading Python to 3.8 but Jupyter notebooks doesn't support the newer Python version yet. Anyone able to get spacy to work with PySpark on Jupyter notebooks?

Comment: Hi @Cryssie, I'm getting the same error as you, have you resolved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Part of the error points to https://github.com/explosion/catalogue/blob/master/catalogue.py#L7, where the import of `importlib.metadata` seems to go wrong, but not with the expected error type `ImportError`. I'll make a PR to include the `ModuleNotFoundError` and let's hope that would fix the issue!

[EDIT:] Hm, `ModuleNotFoundError` is a subclass of `ImportError` so I don't understand why that is not properly caught in the `except` block :|

[EDIT 2:] Logged an issue https://github.com/explosion/catalogue/issues/4 in case this is indeed related to `catalogue.py`

Comment: I actually tried to remove that try exception block and replace the import statement with just "import importlib_metadata" which resolve the error but the main error is still "OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\C:\ ... "